# java, why thread.wait() don't work in my code

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

I have a screenplay(Thread) print several pieces of texts circularly，and  there is a screenbreak to print  urgent texts, and when screenbreak prints, it should wait screenplay first. After screenbreak print all texts, it will notify screenplay, and screenplay begin its printing.

```
class ScreenPlay implements Runnable{

    public synchronized void notifys() throws InterruptedException {
      notify();
    }

    public synchronized void waits() throws InterruptedException {
      wait();
    }

    public void run(){
      for(int i=0; i<15; i++){   
          System.out.println(i);
          try{
            Thread.sleep(500); 
          }catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
          if( i == 14 ){
              i = -1;
          }
      }
    }
}

class ScreenBreak implements Runnable{
  private ScreenPlay screenplay;

  public ScreenBreak(ScreenPlay screenplay){
    this.screenplay = screenplay;
  }

  public void run(){
    try{
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      screenplay.waits();
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
      System.out.println("@_" + i);
    }
    try{
      Thread.sleep(5000);
      screenplay.notifys();
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}

public class Waits {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      ScreenPlay s = new ScreenPlay();
      ScreenBreak sb = new ScreenBreak(s);
      new Thread(s).start();
      new Thread(sb).start();

    }
}
```

the output shows 'wait()' don't work at all, screenplay continues print. screenbreak never print its texts.
why? what wrong here?

I modify code and it works.

```
class ScreenPlay implements Runnable{

    private int waittime = 1050;
    private boolean isPause = false;

    public synchronized  void setIsPause(boolean isPause){
      this.isPause = isPause;
    }

    public synchronized void go() throws InterruptedException {
      this.isPause = false;
      notify();
    }

    public void run(){
      for(int i=0; i<15; i++){   
          System.out.println(i);
          try{
            for(int j = 0; j < waittime/500 + 1; j++){
              Thread.sleep(500); 
              synchronized(this){
                if(isPause){
                  System.out.println("waiting");
                 wait();
                }else{
                  System.out.println("..."); 
                }
              }
            }
          }catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
          if( i == 14 ){
              i = -1;
          }
      }
    }
}

class ScreenBreak implements Runnable{
  private ScreenPlay screenplay;

  public ScreenBreak(ScreenPlay screenplay){
    this.screenplay = screenplay;
  }

  public void run(){
    try{
      Thread.sleep(2000);
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    screenplay.setIsPause(true);
    try{
      Thread.sleep(5000);
      for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
          System.out.println("@_" + i);
      }
      screenplay.go();
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

}

public class Waits {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      ScreenPlay s = new ScreenPlay();
      ScreenBreak sb = new ScreenBreak(s);
      new Thread(s).start();
      new Thread(sb).start();
      try{
        Thread.sleep(15000);
      }catch(InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      new Thread(sb).start();

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of your `waits()` method?  The only thing it does is it lets you write `screenplay.waits()` instead of writing `screenplay.wait()`.  How does that help anything?  Ditto for your `notifys()` method.

Comment: @james large How can I wait a thread out of that thread? Use a volatile variable , wait() when true. There is a sleep(), when time is long, urgent text won't be printed immediatly.

Comment: @jameslarge The most important thing is it WON'T wait screenplay. There is a synchronized word  before waits, there may be some diff between them I think.

Comment: Oops!  I missed seeing the `synchronized`.  I am not used to seeing `synchronized` in front of a method name because, IMO, synchronizing whole methods is bad design.

Comment: @jameslarge I modify code and it works, please figure out  shortcomings  to make it work better.I theck if there is a wait() every 0.5 second which may waste CPU resouce. Do you have good idea of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `ScreenBreak` starts `wait()`ing, there's nobody to `notify()` it. The only call to `notify()` is in `ScreenBreak`, but it'll never get there since it's stuck at `wait()`.

Recommendation: back to the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html)

Comment: You mean screenplay.waits() makes screenbreak wait but not screenplay.

Comment: Well, technically calling `wait()` makes the current thread wait (which in this case is the one that's running ScreenBreak).

Comment: Lately I've been learning to say "the caller" or "the calling thread" instead of "the _current_ thread."  That's ever since I saw one of these noobs comment, "I don't understand; Which thread will be returned by `Thread.getCurrentThread()` when the system has more than one CPU?"